# Sizes in dimens.xml are what we see there?

Tags: android

In my `dimens.xml` I have:

```
<dimen name="small_title">7sp</dimen>
```

In code I have:

```
Logger.i(getClass(), "size is " + getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.small_title));
```

which gives me:

```
size is 10.5
```

Why is that so and how can I get `7sp` as it is stated in `dimens.xml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **sp** Scale-independent Pixels - this is like the dp unit, but it is also
> scaled by the user's font size preference. It is recommend you use
> this unit when specifying font sizes, so they will be adjusted for
> both the screen density and user's preference.

That's why.

Also have a look at [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimension%28int%29)

> Unit conversions are based on the current DisplayMetrics associated
> with the resources.